# How to bind an event handler to the removal of an array-item using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, event-handling

So I have 4 facets to this mini-program I'm toying with:

1. the main display (which displays inputted strings 1 at a time);
2. the form where user inputs words;
3. an independent array that stores each user's inputted strings; and
4. a control panel (mini display) that displays all of the user's current inputted-strings.

Currently, when the user inputs a string, it gets sent to the container-array. From the array, it goes to BOTH the display and the control panel. I've added an event-handler function that allows the user to double-click on the entry in the control panel, which then deletes that entry from the control panel only... (but I need that double-click event to also remove the entry from the array)

```
$(".controlbox").on('dblclick', 'p', function() {
    $(this).closest('p').remove();
});
```

SEE original code:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/sKadX/9/)

...

So, how would I bind this event handler so that it also results in the removal of the entry from the container-array??? (it follows that this would also result in the entry's removal from the main display, which is what I'm aiming for)

I would like the user to be able to delete entries from the control panel, as opposed to having to delete elements of the array from the array. In other words, I would like the control panel to act as a control panel, and therefore need to somehow link that event handler back to the container-array....

Comment: Why not just search the Array for the item's text that was double clicked, and then remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can relate the entries in the console (the ones that are double-clicked) back to the entries in the container-array by index. That is, the entries in the console make up the list of children of the ".container" element and have the same indexes as the entries in the container-array.

Therefore, you can use the following to remove the entries from the container array.

```
$(".controlbox").on('dblclick', 'p', function() {
    var $entry = $(this);
    container.splice($entry.index(), 1);
    $entry.remove();
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p35FF/)

Comment: WOW! Ok so that definitely works. Give me a little bit of time please to go over the code and analyze it to see why it works and I'll check and up vote this answer. THANK YOU

Comment: So... line 15/16 of JS in your jsfiddle, that's where the user input is added to both the container-array and the console at the same time, right? So they should have the same index # when going to remove them later on...Then in your dbl-click event handler, take the index of whatever entry is removed - take its console-index and use that console index to splice and remove its same index # from the container-array (line 56)... And also, remove the clicked-on entry from the console, as well (line 57)...

Comment: Thanks again for this btw - it's exactly what I was looking to accomplish

Comment: @Seeeyonnn - Exactly. The jquery `.index()` function comes in handy for this. And the javascript `splice` function is the way to remove an element from an array.

Comment: so I've long since updated the code @John S. Now when I double click to remove - the elements are no longer removed from the container and they are still displayed. You think you could take a look? The relevant code is on line 453. Try going down to the console (bottom of the result) and navigate to the "Your Aspirations" option - if you add an entry and then delete it by double clicking, it will still display... Thoughts? http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/L3WyW/

Comment: Ayy I think I was able to fix it by adding 1 to $entry.index()

Comment: @Seeeyonnn - The last thing you do in the double-click handler is call `display()`, that function randomizes the `container` array, but the order in the console has not changed. So when a second entry is double-clicked, the wrong entry is deleted. You cannot re-order the `container` unless you also re-order the console. They must be kept in sync at all times.

Comment: Ayyyy I see. So the randomizing kind of messes it up. Hmmmmm. Trying to think of a way around this... Thanks for the help @John S